# wss 3.0 content database has expanded exponentially without any data added in it

Tags: web-part, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, wss-3.0, sql-server

I am hosting wss 3.0 web application in windows 2003 server with sql 2005 express edition. we are leveraging lots of out of the box functionality, but we also have some custom features and web parts. Recently we were having very very slow performance in the site. I found out one of the custom feature was looping infinitely. Feature concatenates two list columns values into another field. After finding that out i killed the workflow attached to that feature. Website started working very fast again.

Everything was going well until i found out the content database that was close to 1.5 gb has turned into 43.6 gb. I have tried restarting timer services, restarted sql server, restarted sharepoint server. I also tried shrinking unused space of the data file using sql management studio shrink funcationality.

So far No Sucess, if anyone has encountered such a issue, please advise.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a similar issue in the past that as due to an errant SharePoint Designer workflow that would double in size each time it was invoked.  The workflow was up to almost 1GB before we were able to stop it. Microsoft was never able to find the issue but we had to remove all traces of the workflow before the problem fully went away.  The performance issue you describe sounds exactly like what we saw.

As far as shrinking the database goes, you might be able to do that after you clean up the workflow (including the history) and then clear the recycle bin.  Failing that, you might need to fully backup your content database and then restore it into a new content database.  However, bear in mind that doing this also causes other issues (like it breaks existing alerts).

Comment: Hello Dave, thank you for your answer. we only had that feature attached to a list. It was working finebut all of a sudden it got stuck and didnt stop and kept looping.  I went into that list and took a look around the list but there isnt any traces of that workflow. Do i need to deactivate that feature from that farm, will that help. If nothing works i will try restoring content db into another content db, but how will tat get rid of unused space?

Comment: We had to pull everything workflow related out of the list including the feature as well as all history, break all associations, kill any workflows that were in process, etc..